# Read and process files in parallel using databricks

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using python in databricks in MS Azure to read multiple groups of csv files stored in a data lake and then perform several transformations. The rows from each files in a group are appended together and then the next group of files are processed and appended. An example is shown below:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(groups)):

  filepath_chosen0 = files_all0[i]
  filepath_chosen1 = files_all1[i]

  df0 = sqlcontext.read.text(filepath_chosen0).toPandas()
  df1 = sqlcontext.read.text(filepath_chosen1).toPandas()

  df00 = process_rows0(df0)
  df11 = process_rows1(df1)

  df2 = pd.concat([df00, df11], axis =1)
  df3 = df3.append(df2)
```

Due to the large number loops, I want to parallelize the above code.

I have used the following code to read all the files in parallel, but I have not been able to perform the required row-wise processing:

```
spk_df1 = spark.read.text(files_all.tolist()).option("header", "true").format("csv").option(delimiter = ',')
```

Any help to reduce the computation time is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. You're using Spark's read.text(?) and then switches immediately to Pandas? What's the point of using Spark at all, if other than the read, all the processing is done with Pandas, on the driver?

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your question. I am using sqlcontext.read.text() only because that was the only way I managed to read the files stored of ADLS Gen2. If there is a more suitable alternative I am more than happy to change.

Comment: You can read azure storage urls directly with pandas

Comment: Thank you again David. Using your suggestion, I have been able to read the files using pandas as shown here: https://pypi.org/project/adlfs/

Comment: Instead of this, use Spark to read files, and then reimplement your functions as Pandas UDFs - then everything will be parallelized

Comment: Thank you Alex for your comment. Can you link me to a minimum working example that used Pandas UDF?